# c# List<Object> group by name and date calculate sum and average to List<Dictionary<string,string>>

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a class:

```
public class Custom
{
   public Custom()
   {

   }

   public DateTime TargetDate { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
   public decimal Value { get; set; }
}


List<Custom> customItems = new List<Custom>();
```

the list above can contain any number of items that can be called same or differently. The items can be in any day, even multiple items called the same on one specific date.

How can I use linq to group the list by name and date, and calculate `sum` for property Price and `average` for property Value.

So basically, the result should be a List> and properties calculated as such for each grouping name + date.

This is what I tried so far.

```
var aggdata = customItems.GroupBy(t => new { t.Name, t.TargetDate.Date })
              .ToDictionary(t => t.Key.Name, t => t.Sum(x => x.Price));
```

But I'm missing the average and date values in the dictionary.

The result should be like this:

```
"TargetDate", "01.01.2015"
"Name", "SomeName"
"Value", "123"   // Average of values
"Price", "1234"  // Sum of price values

.........
```

Answer (score 2):

You can project to an anonymous object with all of the properties that you need. That dictionary projection will be problematic if you have that name across multiple dates. You'll probably want to project to Lookup instead. That allows you to have multiple keys.

```
var aggdata = customItems.GroupBy(t => new { t.Name, t.TargetDate.Date })
          .ToLookup(t => t.Key.Name, t => new {
              Date = t.Key.Date,
              Average = t.Average(x => x.Value),
              Sum = t.Sum(x => x.Price)
          });
```

Comment: Just a note on this; this will fail if you have two names on the same date (it will create two groups, but try to insert the duplicate name into the dictionary). This actually comes from the original post's requirement, but it seems to me that the key should be the grouping object, rather than the name... but that depends on @user2818430's requirement

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var query =
    from ci in customItems
    group ci by new { ci.TargetDate, ci.Name } into gcis
    select new Custom()
    {
        TargetDate = gcis.Key.TargetDate,
        Name = gcis.Key.Name,
        Price = gcis.Sum(x => x.Price),
        Value = gcis.Average(x => x.Value),
    };

List<Custom> results = query.ToList();
```

With this sample data:

```
List<Custom> customItems = new List<Custom>()
{
    new Custom() { TargetDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Name = "Foo", Price = 1m, Value = 2m, },
    new Custom() { TargetDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Name = "Foo", Price = 2m, Value = 4m, },
    new Custom() { TargetDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Name = "Bar", Price = 3m, Value = 8m, },
};
```

I get these results:

[image: results]